# Foreman can't connect to potsgresql server (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This is my first time using postgresql. I have checked and the server definitely seems to be running but I am getting this error when I start foreman

```
[...]postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::Error)
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I opened pgAdmin and the db is set to listen on port 8000 instead of 5432 (which seems to be what rails wants). I have tried creating a new connection and setting it to 5432 but I get this error:

Server doesn't listen

The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Foreman to work again by modifying my `database.yml` file. I had to change the port to `8000` (which postgres was listening on).

Comment: This is very odd, though I am glad you got it working. At the beginning of your postgresql.conf file, in the Connections and Authentication section, you will find an entry for the port the database is listening on. Did you check that?

Comment: @thisfeller I did. The port in the conf file was 5432 but the database was listening in 8000. I tried creating a new database on 5432 but kept getting the error I added to my question. Setting the port in database.yml solved it. I think I set the port wrong when installing postgres.

Comment: OK, you should be able to open a console, become root, then become the postgres user (or maybe the _postgres user), stop and restart the database with pg_ctl after changing the port line in the config file.

Comment: @thisfeller I tried that but the database port remained 8000 and I was still blocked from creating a new one of the correct port.

Comment: Well, if you installed twice, you might not be looking at the right config file! There should be one and only one engine, but there can be many databases. How do you actually stop postgres?

Comment: @thisfeller I'm pretty sure I didn't install it twice. To stop it running I do sudo su, cd to the Library/PostgreSQL/9.1 directory and run: sudo -u postgres ./pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data stop -m fast

Comment: @thisfeller After stopping postgres via the command above I can't restart it. I'm getting the error: BST FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory

Comment: Just to clear it up I completed uninstalled then reinstalled postgres and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: Glad you cleared it up. Postgresql on Lion has become painful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port did not work for me. I installed postgres on Mac using the [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_3)

I had to update the Rails DB config (database.yml) to add the host field and set it to localhost and dropped the username and password fields

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: project_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
```

After fixing that the error was about the database that I was connecting to not existing. To fix that, connect to postgres using psql and create the database

```
CREATE DATABASE project_development;
```

Replace the DB name with the right one for your case.

Also Postgres.app docs have additional info for configuring in other environments
http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_3